# Bigcommerce API connection disconnects with no response

Tags: python-3.x, api, bigcommerce

We've been using a Python script to pull orders from our BigCommerce store and reformat them into a .csv for use by our warehouse. This method has been working for the past 3 years yet since the 16 September 2020 our connection has started dropping without a response.

Full response is:

```
Downloading Order: 1541
WPy64-3720\python-3.7.2.amd64\python.exe : Traceback (most recent call last):
At D:\Administration\Scripts\re_orders\reau-orders.ps1:7 char:28
+ $OrdersProcessingOutput = (WPy64-3720\python-3.7.2.amd64\python.exe bcOrdersREAU ...
+                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Traceback (most recent call last)::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
  File "D:\Administration\Scripts\re_orders\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "D:\Administration\Scripts\re_orders\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "D:\Administration\Scripts\re_orders\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "D:\Administration\Scripts\re_orders\WPy64-3720\python-3.7.2.amd64\lib\http\client.py", line 1321, in
getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "D:\Administration\Scripts\re_orders\WPy64-3720\python-3.7.2.amd64\lib\http\client.py", line 296, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "D:\Administration\Scripts\re_orders\WPy64-3720\python-3.7.2.amd64\lib\http\client.py", line 265, in
_read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Administration\Scripts\re_orders\requests\adapters.py", line 438, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "D:\Administration\Scripts\re_orders\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 649, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "D:\Administration\Scripts\re_orders\requests\packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 357, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "D:\Administration\Scripts\re_orders\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "D:\Administration\Scripts\re_orders\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "D:\Administration\Scripts\re_orders\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "D:\Administration\Scripts\re_orders\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "D:\Administration\Scripts\re_orders\WPy64-3720\python-3.7.2.amd64\lib\http\client.py", line 1321, in
getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "D:\Administration\Scripts\re_orders\WPy64-3720\python-3.7.2.amd64\lib\http\client.py", line 296, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "D:\Administration\Scripts\re_orders\WPy64-3720\python-3.7.2.amd64\lib\http\client.py", line 265, in
_read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed
connection without response'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bcOrdersREAU.py", line 1254, in <module>
    checkPendingPayments(basePath + pendingPayFile)
  File "bcOrdersREAU.py", line 915, in checkPendingPayments
    getOrders(orderId,orderId)
  File "bcOrdersREAU.py", line 249, in getOrders
    orderJSON = getOrder(headers,orderNo)
  File "D:\Administration\Scripts\re_orders\tenacity\__init__.py", line 333, in wrapped_f
    return self(f, *args, **kw)
  File "D:\Administration\Scripts\re_orders\tenacity\__init__.py", line 417, in __call__
    do = self.iter(retry_state=retry_state)
  File "D:\Administration\Scripts\re_orders\tenacity\__init__.py", line 360, in iter
    return fut.result()
  File "D:\Administration\Scripts\re_orders\WPy64-3720\python-3.7.2.amd64\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 425,
in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "D:\Administration\Scripts\re_orders\WPy64-3720\python-3.7.2.amd64\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 384,
in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "D:\Administration\Scripts\re_orders\tenacity\__init__.py", line 420, in __call__
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bc
OrdersREAU.py", line 1155, in getOrder
    order = session.get(ApiPath2 + 'orders/' + str(orderNo), headers=headers)
  File "D:\Administration\Scripts\re_orders\requests\sessions.py", line 531, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Administration\Scripts\re_orders\requests\sessions.py", line 518, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "D:\Administration\Scripts\re_orders\requests\sessions.py", line 639, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Administration\Scripts\re_orders\requests\adapters.py", line 488, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without
response'))
```

The code we're using runs daily and is essentially just iterating through new orders and pulling the details down, including the ordered products. Something like:

requests.get(ApiPath2 + 'orders/' + str(orderNo), headers=headers)
session.get(ApiPath2 + 'orders/' + str(orderNo) + '/products?page=' + str(page), headers=headers)

It doesn't fail every day but has started to be almost a daily occurrence now.

What we have tried:

- new API credentials
- different servers on a different network (Aus + Europe)
- Running the script at different times

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Currently we just keep re running the code manually until it works.

Answer (score 0):

Per [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html)

self.send_header('Content-Type', 'blabla' )

self.end_headers()